# Showing the integral $\int_{C_N} \frac{1}{(2z-1)\sin{\pi z}}dz$ converges to zero as $N \to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have a question about the 10th question part b of Chapter 11 of the Complex Analysis by Bak & Newman. The question says that

Show that $1-1/3+1/5-1/7+...=\pi/4$ by using the integral of $\frac{1}{(2z-1)\sin{\pi z}}$ over a suitable contour. I think the contour must be the square with vertices $\pm (N+1/2) \pm (N+1/2)i$. If the integral of $\frac{1}{(2z-1)\sin{\pi z}}$ over that square converges to zero as $N \to \infty$, the the sum of all residues is zero as $N \to \infty$ and the answer can be found.

However, I stuck to find that convergence. The length-maximum test does not work here because $|\sin{\pi z}|$ may get lower values, so $|\csc{\pi z}|$ will be bounded below.

Note that $|\int_{C_N}{\frac{1}{(2z-1)\sin{\pi z}}}| \leq (8N+4)\frac{1}{2N-1/2}|\csc{\pi z}|_{\text{max}}$

PS: I have already know the sine function grows faster in imaginary part. The problem is related to left and right edges of the contour.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to observe the growth of $|\sin(\pi z)|$ with the imaginary part of $z$. To wit, render $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$, and then

$\sin \pi z=\sin \pi x\cosh \pi y+\cos \pi x\sinh \pi y$

$|\sin \pi z|^2=(1-\cos^2 \pi x)\cosh^2\pi y+\cos^2 \pi x(\cosh^2 \pi y-1)$

$=\cosh^2 \pi y-\cos^2\pi x.$

Thereby the magnitude of the sine function increases exponentially with that of the imaginary part, which should be fast enough to squeeze each segment of the contour integral. The horizontal segments are exponentially small, and the vertical segments are rendered $O(1/N)$ by comparison of the differential with $\exp(-\pi |xy|) dy$ where $|x|=N+(1/2)$ on the vertical segments.

Comment: Oscar, sorry. My method does not work and i deleted it.